# Get userID with the new JS SDK

Tags: userid, facebook-javascript-sdk

how would you do something like:
strUserID = FB.getSession().uid;
with the new JS SDK?
simple call to get the users id after logged in?

Answer (score 0):

REF: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
  } else {
    // no user session available, someone you dont know
  }
});
```

Response:

```
{
    status: 'connected',
    authResponse: {
        accessToken: '...',
        expiresIn:'...',
        signedRequest:'...',
        userID:'...'
    }
}
```